# Adding multiselect dropdown in Admin customer details form in prestashop

Tags: admin, prestashop-1.6

I have added a multiselect dropdown field in customer adding form in admin. I have created new field in database. But I am not getting how to store the value of this new field to database. Please help

I have added this code to AdminCustomersController.php

array(

```
                 'type' => 'select',
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => $this->l('Branch Location'),
                'name' => 'branch_location',
                'required' => false,
                'options' => array(
                    'query' => $list_branch_arr,
                    'id' => 'branch_location',
                    'name' => 'name'
                ),
                'col' => '4',
                'hint' => array(
                    $this->l('Please choose the branch name from the branch list.')
                )
```

But no idea how to insert the selected values to database

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the new field to the Customer Model.
/prestashop/classess/Customer.php

After

```
    /** @var string Object last modification date */
public $date_upd;
```

add :

```
public $branch_location;
```

and modify :

```
public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'customer',
    'primary' => 'id_customer',
    'fields' => array(
        'secure_key' =>                 array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isMd5', 'copy_post' => false),
        'lastname' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'firstname' =>                  array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'email' =>                      array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isEmail', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
        'passwd' =>                     array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPasswd', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'last_passwd_gen' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_gender' =>                  array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
        'birthday' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isBirthDate'),
        'newsletter' =>                 array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
        'newsletter_date_add' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE,'copy_post' => false),
        'ip_registration_newsletter' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'copy_post' => false),
        'optin' =>                      array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
        'website' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isUrl'),
        'company' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName'),
        'siret' =>                      array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isSiret'),
        'ape' =>                        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isApe'),
        'outstanding_allow_amount' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'validate' => 'isFloat', 'copy_post' => false),
        'show_public_prices' =>         array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_risk' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt', 'copy_post' => false),
        'max_payment_days' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt', 'copy_post' => false),
        'active' =>                     array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'deleted' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'note' =>                       array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'size' => 65000, 'copy_post' => false),
        'is_guest' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_shop' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_shop_group' =>              array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_default_group' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_lang' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_add' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_upd' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
    ),
);
```

to :

```
    public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'customer',
    'primary' => 'id_customer',
    'fields' => array(
        'secure_key' =>                 array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isMd5', 'copy_post' => false),
        'lastname' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'firstname' =>                  array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'email' =>                      array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isEmail', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
        'passwd' =>                     array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPasswd', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'last_passwd_gen' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_gender' =>                  array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId'),
        'birthday' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isBirthDate'),
        'newsletter' =>                 array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
        'newsletter_date_add' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE,'copy_post' => false),
        'ip_registration_newsletter' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'copy_post' => false),
        'optin' =>                      array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),
        'website' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isUrl'),
        'company' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName'),
        'siret' =>                      array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isSiret'),
        'ape' =>                        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isApe'),
        'outstanding_allow_amount' =>   array('type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'validate' => 'isFloat', 'copy_post' => false),
        'show_public_prices' =>         array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_risk' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt', 'copy_post' => false),
        'max_payment_days' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt', 'copy_post' => false),
        'active' =>                     array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'deleted' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'note' =>                       array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'size' => 65000, 'copy_post' => false),
        'is_guest' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_shop' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_shop_group' =>              array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_default_group' =>           array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_lang' =>                    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_add' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_upd' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
        'branch_location' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_INT),
    ),
);
```

Comment: I tried this but only one value is saved from the multi select dropdown. Do I need to change anything else like adding foreach loop or something @WEBDEV AD

Answer (score 0):

the answer are not correctly .. due its not only dfined the field in the database, also must capture and stored in special way the values, in this example i demostrate to store as "1,2,3,6,8" using a single field

THE COMPLETE CODE AND ALL THE STEPS ARE AT: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?hl=es#!topic/venenuxsarisari/z8vfPsvFFjk

here i put only the most important parts..

as mentioned int he previous link, added a new fiel in the model definition, class and the table sql

**this method permits to stored in the db as "1,2,3" so you can use only a single field** to relation that multiple selected values, **a better could be using groupbox** *but its quite difficult*, take a look to the AdminCustomers controller class in the controllers directory of the prestachop, this has a multiselect group that used a relational table event stored in single field

then in the helper form list array of inputs define a select as:

at the begining dont foget to added that line:

```
// aqui el truco de guardar el multiselect como una secuencia separada por comas, mejor es serializada pero bueh
$this->fields_value['id_employee[]'] = explode(',',$obj->id_employee);
```

this $obj are the representation of the loaded previous stored value when go to edit ... from that object, get the stored value of the field of your multiselect, stored as "1,3,4,6"

and the in the field form helper list of inputs define the select multiple as:

```
            array(
                 'type' => 'select',
                'label' => $this->l('Select and employee'),
                'name' => 'id_employee_tech',
                'required' => false,
                'col' => '6',
                'default_value' => (int)Tools::getValue('id_employee_tech'),
                'options' => array(
                    'query' => Employee::getEmployees(true), // el true es que solo los que estan activos
                    'id' => 'id_employee',
                    'name' => 'firstname',
                    'default' => array(
                        'value' => '',
                        'label' => $this->l('ninguno')
                    )
                )
            ),
```

an then override the post process too

```
public function postProcess()
{
    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitTallerOrden'))
    {
        $_POST['id_employee'] = implode(',', Tools::getValue('id_employee'));
    }
    parent::postProcess();
}
```

this make stored in the db as "1,2,3"